# React dynamic component with SVG and array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a React dynamic component with a SVG file that is imported from another file. The `e` on `tech.forEach` is a string, I already printed on console and it's fine.

**The problem:**
The component `<LogoComponent logo={e}>` doesn't render.

How can I make this work? `tech` is an array that comes from another component as *props*, and it's ok on console too.

*Thanks in advance!*

**index.js**

```
import * as S from './style';
import LogoComponent from '../../Utils/icons';

function Works({
  description1,
  description2,
  type,
  title,
  background,
  image,
  tech
  }) {

  return(
    <S.Container>
   
      <S.Image style={{backgroundImage:`url(${image})`}}/>
      <S.Details>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{description1}</p>
        <p>{description2}</p>
        <div className="icons">
          {
            tech.forEach((e) =>(
              <LogoComponent logo={e}/>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </S.Details>

    </S.Container>
  );
}

export default Works;
```

**icons.js**

```
import { ReactComponent as LogoBlender} from '../Assets/Images/logo_blender.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoCSharp} from '../Assets/Images/logo_csharp.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoCpp} from '../Assets/Images/logo_cpp.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoFreeglut} from '../Assets/Images/logo_freeglut.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoJS} from '../Assets/Images/logo_js.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoMysql} from '../Assets/Images/logo_mysql.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoPHP} from '../Assets/Images/logo_php.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoReact} from '../Assets/Images/logo_react.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoThree} from '../Assets/Images/logo_three.svg';
import { ReactComponent as LogoUnity} from '../Assets/Images/logo_unity.svg';

const logos = {
    blender: LogoBlender,
    csharp: LogoCSharp,
    cpp: LogoCpp,
    freeglut: LogoFreeglut,
    js: LogoJS,
    mysql: LogoMysql,
    php: LogoPHP,
    react: LogoReact,
    three: LogoThree,
    unity: LogoUnity
};

export default function LogoComponent(props){
  const SelectLogo = logos[props.logo];
  return <SelectLogo/>;
};
```

Comment: you need to use `map()` instead of `forEach()` so that it returns an array of components. (`forEach()` returns `undefined`)

Comment: Yes, changed here. But no success yet. Thanks.

Comment: I solved this with 10 ```if - else if``` conditions so far. I know, it's an ugly solution, but I need to move on. If someone have a suggestion for this it would be great.